# Undefined variable in Database

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined variable: mypassword in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Databasetesting\Checklogin.php on line 16

and my Line 16 is here:

`$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);`

and here is my Entire Code i use this for Html5.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$host="localhost";
$username="jerome";
$password="jeromedizon";
$db_name="portal_database";
$tbl_name="members"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select Database mebers");

$mystudnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studnum']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
$mystudnum = stripslashes($mystudnum);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$mystudnum = mysql_real_escape_string($mystudnum);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE studnum='$mystudnum' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

    $_SESSION['mystudnum'] = $mystudnum;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
    header("location: Home.php");
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: You're using the same variable for two different things. Is `$password` supposed to be the database password or the password submitted by the user?

Comment: $password for database password and $mypassword for the password that submitted by the user

Comment: For goodness' sake read your error messages; it could not be any clearer what it means... it even gives you the file name and line number. This is *not* difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line 16 needs to be:

```php
$mypassword = stripslashes($password);
```

The error occurs because `$mypassword` is not defined before this line, but `$password` is indeed!

Comment: so do i need to change my entire code? im sorry. im just new in web programming :/

Comment: No, changing line 16 should be enough ;-) It's just a matter of defining variables that you use before you use them, in your case `$password` is defined on line 6, but `$mypassword` is not usable until line 17, because it's defined first in line 16.

Comment: thanks :) i got now is that it wont redirect to Home.php when i logged in :/

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as correct if it helped you ! That helps users encountering the same problems to find the correct answer!

Comment: @Ejay If you intend to deploy your application productively, please consider SQL injection attacks. Your code is quite vulnerable at the moment ;-)

Comment: i will just run this on localhost.

Comment: @UliKöhler Isn't that why he calls `mysql_real_escape_string`, to protect against injection?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're right, I just tried to edit the comment. Must have overlooked that. It could be vulnerable the way you're assembling statements, but you're doing escaping, so in this particular case and state of code, there's probably no such vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo change:

```
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
```

to

```
$mypassword =  stripslashes($password);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));`? All the other variables from form inputs are `$myXXX`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, if it was me I would grossly simplify this... but I think he is new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
```

to:

```
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
```

You're already using `$password` for the database password. And all the other variables yo assigned from `$_POST` use `$myXXX` names, so this will be more consistent.

Also, you shouldn't call `stripslashes` on the result of `mysql_real_escape_string`. `mysql_real_escape_string` adds slashes to implement the escaping, so you're undoing this.

You're also escaping some strings twice. You have:

```
$mystudnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studnum']);
```

followed a few lines later by :

```
$mystudnum = mysql_real_escape_string($mystudnum);
```

You should only do it once.

Comment: im just new in webprogramming. and it makes me confused :/

Comment: What part is confusing you?

Comment: i dont know where i went wrong. but when i log in to main login page it keeps on redirecting to this Checklogin page.

Comment: I thought you meant my answer was confusing you. You have a number of problems in your code, you need to study PHP some more. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for learning what you're doing.